# Iterating through dates using a 12 months period starting from a certain month

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ab0174b094f8783ba57f1dbc9cf4cae0)**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date DATE,
    customer VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers
(order_date, customer)
VALUES 
('2020-05-10', 'user_01'),
('2020-05-15', 'user_01'),
('2020-05-18', 'user_02'),
('2020-05-26', 'user_03'),

('2020-06-03', 'user_04'),
('2020-06-05', 'user_05'),
('2020-06-24', 'user_06'),


('2021-05-02', 'user_01'),
('2021-05-05', 'user_01'),
('2021-05-12', 'user_03'),
('2021-05-20', 'user_07'),

('2021-06-08', 'user_04'),
('2021-06-20', 'user_06'),
('2021-06-21', 'user_08'),
('2021-06-25', 'user_08'),
('2021-06-25', 'user_09');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
order_date   |   customer  |  
-------------|-------------|----
2021-05-02   |   user_01   |  
2021-05-05   |   user_01   |  
2021-05-12   |   user_03   |  
-------------|-------------|----
2021-06-08   |   user_04   |  
2021-06-20   |   user_06   |
```

---

I want to list all customers in a certain month which

a) have **not** been **existing** in the past **12 months** and 
b) already **existed before** this period of **12 months**.

---

For a **single month** I am able to achieve this by using this query:

```
SELECT
c1.order_date,
c1.customer
FROM customers c1
WHERE c1.order_date BETWEEN '2021-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-05-31 23:59:59'

/* Check if customer exists in the past 12 months */
AND NOT EXISTS

   (SELECT
    c2.customer
    FROM customers c2
    WHERE c2.order_date BETWEEN '2020-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-04-30 23:59:59'
    AND c2.customer = c1.customer)

/* Check if customer exists before the past 12 months */
AND EXISTS

   (SELECT
    c2.customer
    FROM customers c2
    WHERE c2.order_date < '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
    AND c2.customer = c1.customer)

ORDER BY 2;
```

---

However, I have to run this query for each month seperatly.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is an **iterating** solution that goes **through multiple months at once**.

In the example above it would run `BETWEEN '2021-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-06-30 23:59:59'` and calculate 12 months back from May and in the next step 12 months back from June to get the expected result.

Do you have any idea if this is possible?

Comment: [`date_trunc('month', order_date)`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date_trunc/) will play a big part in the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
t1.order_date, 
t1.customer
FROM 

  (SELECT
   c.customer,
   c.order_date,
   LAG(c.order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY c.customer ORDER BY c.order_date) AS prev_order_date
   FROM customers c) t1

WHERE t1.order_date BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2021-06-30' 
AND t1.prev_order_date >= date_trunc('month', t1.order_date) - interval '12 month'
AND t1.prev_order_date < date_trunc('month', t1.order_date)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e77ff93fe8daad862c7d545e9dcfd478)**